# How to calculate Distance between Two Zipcodes in Miles Using R

Tags: r

I wanted to calculate the distance between two zip codes. Is there any particular function to find the distance?

I used this code

```
Dataframe <- transform(dataframe, Distance = ifelse(a == "" | b == "", "", georoute( c("a", "b"), verbose=TRUE, returntype="distance", service="bing" )))
```

Where `a` and `b` are two separate columns which contain zipcodes of two different areas.

I used the code given at [Determing the distance between two ZIP codes (alternatives to mapdist)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17361909/602276)

Comment: Thanks for the Edit Andrie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find online a table that has longitudes and latitudes for 29,000+ US cities, along with their zip codes.  with it you could then convert your columns of zip codes to coordinates.

Then, the `geosphere` package offers eight functions for calculating distances (great circle, Haversine, Rhumb, etc) based on coordinates.  It also converts meters to miles.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the function to be used. I just need the Distances between two points(distance by car) to be used in the dataframe for other purpose. I have calculated the Latitude and Longitude. The function which u mentioned, are used for plotting i guess (Please ignore if im wrong im new to R)

Comment: Read the pdf of the geosphere package and decide which calculation of distance makes sense for you.  I do not think driving distance is included, by the way, but you may or may not actually need that.  Yes, they are used for plotting, but also can be independent.

Comment: I Used different functions to caluclate the distance and there was a huge difference in the values can u suggest which is accurate   1.  'mapdist('28202', '98032', mode = 'driving')'
**from    to       m       km    miles seconds minutes   hours
28202 98032 4507924 4507.924 2801.224  145935 2432.25 40.5375**   
2. 'distHaversine(c(-80.84419, 35.22719), c(-122.25932, 47.38825))'
**3666598**           
3. 'distVincentySphere(c(-80.84419, 35.22719), c(-122.25932, 47.38825))'
**3666598**

Comment: I do not know.  You can always write the package maintainer, send your data in a reproducible fashion and they are usually delighted to hear from users.  BTW, if the answer has been useful, would you accept it?